# how to use composer autoloader with __autoload?

Tags: php, composer-php

my composer.json content is:

```
{
    "require": {
        "rlanvin/php-rrule": "1.*"
    }
}
```

my own autolader is:

```
function __autoload($class_name) {
    include __DIR__.'/classes/'.$class_name . '.php';
}
```

Problem is: when I want to add tha composer autoloader with

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
```

My own autoloader does not work any more. (Class not found !)

How to make noth work (the composer autolader and mine) ?

regards

I tried:

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
User::get(1);
```

User.php is in /classes

composer.json

```
{
    "require": {
        "rlanvin/php-rrule": "1.*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": { 
            "": "classes" 
        }
    }
}
```

and 'got Class User not found'

It works find with my autloader:

function **autoload($class_name) {
    include __DIR**.'/classes/'.$class_name . '.php';
}

Comment: Have as many autoload functions as you want: ... use [spl_autoload_register -  Register given function as __autoload() implementation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php). Also: [How to use spl_autoload_register?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11131238/how-to-use-spl-autoload-register). They are called in sequence until a class is loaded. very useful.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need your autoloader. Composer has plenty of [options](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#autoload): PSR-0, PSR-4, classmap and files. Try [`classmap`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#classmap).

```json
{
    "require": {
        "rlanvin/php-rrule": "1.*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "classes"
        ]
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATED:** Or even better use [psr-0](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#psr-0) in the following way

```
{
    "require": {
        "rlanvin/php-rrule": "1.*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": { 
            "": "classes" 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did not help: Class not found. I am using: require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

Comment: No: shoud I run that ?  I just did and did not help

Comment: Still : Class User not found: Infact it looks like composer.json is ... totally ignored ! When I delete composer.json or rename it or change its content: it has no effect at all

Comment: Try running `composer dump` to update `autoload.php`

Comment: That composer dump did it. Thanks!